# Using survfit object's formula in survdiff call

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm doing some survival analysis in R, and looking to tidy up/simplify my code.

At the moment I'm doing several steps in my data analysis:

1. make a Surv object (time variable with indication as to whether each observation was censored);
2. fit this Surv object according to a categorical predictor, for plotting/estimation of median survival time processes; and
3. calculate a log-rank test to ask whether there is evidence of "significant" differences in survival between the groups.

As an example, here is a mock-up using the lung dataset in the survival package from R. So the following code is similar enough to what I want to do, but much simplified in terms of the predictor set (which is why I want to simplify the code, so I don't make inconsistent calls across models).

```
library(survival)

# Step 1: Make a survival object with time-to-event and censoring indicator.
# Following works with defaults as status = 2 = dead in this dataset.
# Create survival object
lung.Surv <- with(lung, Surv(time=time, event=status))

# Step 2: Fit survival curves to object based on patient sex, plot this.
lung.survfit <- survfit(lung.Surv ~ lung$sex)
print(lung.survfit)
plot(lung.survfit)

# Step 3: Calculate log-rank test for difference in survival objects
lung.survdiff <- survdiff(lung.Surv ~ lung$sex)
print(lung.survdiff)
```

Now this is all fine and dandy, and I can live with this but would like to do better.

So my question is around step 3. What I would like to do here is to be able to use information in the formula from the lung.survfit object to feed into the calculation of the differences in survival curves: i.e. in the call to survdiff. And this is where my domitable [sic] programming skills hit a wall. Below is my current attempt to do this: I'd appreciate any help that you can give! Once I can get this sorted out I should be able to wrap a solution up in a function.

```
lung.survdiff <- survdiff(parse(text=(lung.survfit$call$formula)))
## Which returns following:
# Error in survdiff(parse(text = (lung.survfit$call$formula))) : 
# The 'formula' argument is not a formula
```

Comment: I had typed this whole question up and formatted it nicely, and then got to wondering if there was an `as.formula` function available in R. Which, of course, there is. So I decided to post the question and answer it myself (as per the FAQ), and so the solution is very simple by replacing the code in Step 3 with:
    `lung.survdiff <- survdiff(as.formula(lung.survfit$call$formula))`

This is one of those "I couldn't think of how to search for what I was looking for" moments...

Comment: thanks for the nicely formulated question and reproducible example. Please do answer your question by posting an answer (as opposed to a comment). Also, you can directly extract the formula using `formula(lung.survfit)`. Whether this will work as expected in your function depends greatly on the exact function itself.

Comment: @BenBarnes That's an even tidier way to extract the formula. Thanks! I've posted an answer below (I had to wait 8 hours to answer due to not yet having enough rep.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I commented above, I actually sorted out the answer to this shortly after having written this question.

So step 3 above could be replaced by:

```
lung.survdiff <- survdiff(formula(lung.survfit$call$formula))
```

But as Ben Barnes points out in the comment to the question, the formula from the survfit object can be more directly extracted with

```
lung.survdiff <- survdiff(formula(lung.survfit))
```

Which is exactly what I wanted and hoped would be available -- thanks Ben!

Comment: It's 10 years later, but I found that the `data` argument had to be specified in the call to `survdiff` if it has not been specified already. That is,


`lung.survfit <- survfit(Surv(time=time, event=status) ~ sex, data=lung)`
`lung.survdiff <- survdiff(formula(lung.survfit), data=lung)`

Comment: @martin Yes, that's correct -- I'd code these with `data=` arguments now, rather than the `with()` specification as per the earlier code.